# How to check if firestore database document exist when given a document id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if a document in firestore exist when given a document id. So far I have tried this:

```
String getUserType(String uid) {
final result = Firestore.instance.collection('patients').document(uid).get();
if (result == null) {
  return 'null';
} else {
  return 'exist';
}
```

Comment: oh, looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012131/flutter-firestore-check-if-document-id-already-exists

Answer (score 2):

you can use `result.exists`.

original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56465899/4465386

```
final result = await Firestore.instance
  .collection('posts')
  .document(docId)
  .get()

if (result == null || !result.exists) {
  // Document with id == docId doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: Why does it show that my doc exist even though its not?

Comment: Is that doc in a collection that you cannot see from the UI ? If yes then manually create that collection from the UI and add a random document. Sometimes the UI does not show you a collection and its content unless you create the collection manually.