# How to check if a document exists in a firestore collection?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to check if a document exists in a colleciton with a specific uid?
For example i have a collection 'hotels' so how do i check if there exists a specific document(uid) and if it does not exist then it needs to setData but if the document already exists then updateData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document("docID").get();

    if (snapShot.exists){

    }
```

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012131/flutter-firestore-check-if-document-id-already-exists)

Comment: answers this question..thank youl.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a document exists, you can just `get()` it.  There is no special operation just to check if a document exists without also reading it.

But in your case, if you want to either create or update a document without knowing if it exists ahead of time, you can simply call [setData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) and pass `merge: true` as the second argument.

Comment: The merge functionality seems very appropriate for this case..very good suggestion..thank you.