# Throw error on creating document if ID exists - Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a situation where I'm writing documents to a collection in firestore but I'm manually setting the IDs. I want to know how can I throw an error if I try to create a document where the ID already exists.

I know I can use `.get()` and the `.exists` [property before writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012131/flutter-firestore-check-if-document-id-already-exists), but that means I now have to read from the db every time I want to write to this collection, which doesn't scale very well imo.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative I can think of is that you have your security rules reject the write operation, and then detect that rejection in the application code.

```
allow create: if true;
allow update: if false;
```

You'd then handle the failure to update as shown in the documentation on [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: Wouldn't the above rules prevent updating the document totally?

Comment: Yes. If you want something more specific to allow updating in certain cases, you can modify the rules to allow that. The important thing about my answer is that by separating the `create` and `update` cases, you can easily set different conditions for them.